# Splitting an Object into many tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Java object called Star that is stored in the database. There are billions of records of this so I want to split this single object onto multiple tables in the database, by a field in Star object called cluster, which takes the values "left", "right", "top", "bottom"

```
 class Star {

    private String Name;
    private String cluster;
  }
```

So instead of having one huge table, I will have four huge tables for the Star object. Is it possible to do this in hibernate? If so, how?

I want to avoid having to create four different Start object: StarLeft, StarRight, StarBottom, and StarTop, so they land on different tables.

**Edit:** Doing this for performance. I don't have a specific database, my application should work with any (Oracle, MySQL, etc..), hence one reason I am using hibernate.

Comment: are you doing this for performance reason or your logic needs you to do so? what is your database?

Comment: I wonder whether billions of records and Hibernate go well together: do your sql yourself, Hibernate will probably give a sub-optimal solution to you.

Comment: Are you still wanting to do it using hibernate?

Comment: @bluevoid Hibernate _is_ very flexible. You can provide your own SQL and just use it as the mapping lib. . .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle it support partitioning, so if your aim is to improve performance you can achieve it at the DB level.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm. Probably other databases too, provide similar features

Comment: I agree this is probably the best solution. I just wanted to mention Postgres supports this as well: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html. As does MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html